# Why did Kenny Ackerman give away the Syringe?

Tags: character-motivation, attack-on-titan

During the 10th episode of *Attack on Titan* Season 3, Kenny Ackerman gives away a syringe to Capt. Levi, why? He's depicted as a survivor, hungry for power character, and still he gives away his only chance to live.

> Not only that, but he gives away the one thing that can make him virtually invincible.

It may be argued that it was an act of redemption, giving the syringe to

> His nephew, after trying to kill him a few times.

But, he doesn't know at that point that he is going to be found before he passes away, let alone by Levi.

So why?

> Why didn't he transform himself into a titan? Was it fear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the syringe turns Eldians into mindless titans. So he wouldn't become invincible, but merely a mindless titan (the kind Levi and the other soldiers were experienced in killing). As Rod had just demonstrated, the transformation could leave one in a pitiful state afterward.

More importantly, Kenny had been hanging onto the syringe hoping for an opportunity to seize the Founding Titan. Now that he lay dying and Eren had escaped, his hope was dashed. By giving Levi the syringe, he could hope that Levi would use it in some unforeseen way to aid his cause. He also likely felt some guilt at having all his comrades die in his attempt to gain the power of the Founding Titan.

Comment: Interesting, I guess my question was predicated on the idea that living as a mindless being would be better than death itself, but your second point puts this into another perspective. Thanks!